# Unsigned long long with negative value

Tags: c, types

while exploring linux code, came across many definition like below. If ULL is unsigned long long, why it has negative value -11?  What the value of below macro?

```
#define BTRFS_FREE_SPACE_OBJECTID -11ULL
```

Comment: `long long` does not have a standard number of bits. By using a negative notation, you get what @Barmar has just commented below, as I type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-11ULL is the same as - (11ULL). 11ULL is an unsigned long long with value 11. If you read up how arithmetic operations on unsigned types work, if the mathematical result does not fit into the range, then the largest value + 1 is added or subtracted repeatedly.

The mathematical result -11 doesn't fit, so the largest unsigned long long + 1 is added, and -11ULL gives ten less than the largest possible unsigned long long value. A huge positive number, not negative.

Answer (score 1):

```
 unsigned int a=-1;
```

is the same as:

```
 unsigned int a=0xffffffff;
```